# Express - cannot lookup view

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have consulted many other similar threads. I have not been able to find an answer.

```
./
  config/
    connection.js
  controllers/
    homeRoutes.js
    index.js
  db/
    schema.db
  models/
    index.js
    User.js
  public/
    css/
      styles.css
  views/
    layouts/
      main.handlebars
  server.js
```

Here is what `homeRoutes.js` looks like:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const { User, BlogPost, Comment } = require('../models');


//TEST - render homepage
router.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.render('main');
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
```

Here is what server.js has (I think the problem is somewhere in here):

```
// DEPENDENCIES
const express = require('express');
const sequelize = require('./config/connection');
const routes = require('./controllers');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');


// HANDLEBARS configuration
// set up Handlebars.js engine
const hbs = exphbs.create({});

// EXPRESS CONFIGURATION
// tells node that we are creating an express server
const app = express();  

// sets an initial port.
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9999;

// inform Express.js on which template engine to use
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Sets up express app to handle data parsing
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(require('./controllers/homeRoutes'));


// tells app what routes to use
app.use(routes);

// Logging DB info
console.log(`Database name: ${sequelize.config.database} \n running on port: 
${sequelize.config.port} \n under hostname: ${sequelize.config.host}`)


// Listener. Ths effectively 'starts' our server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Node Server running on port: ${PORT}`);
})
```

When I run the server and go to my route, which is localhost:9999/test I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "main" in views directory "/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Coding Bootcamp/Week14/ur-rich-fsf-pt-02-2021-u-c/Bootcamp14_TechBlog/views"
    at Function.render (/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Coding Bootcamp/Week14/ur-rich-fsf-pt-02-2021-u-c/Bootcamp14_TechBlog/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Coding Bootcamp/Week14/ur-rich-fsf-pt-02-2021-u-c/Bootcamp14_TechBlog/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at /Users/ep9k/Desktop/Coding Bootcamp/Week14/ur-rich-fsf-pt-02-2021-u-c/Bootcamp14_TechBlog/controllers/homeRoutes.js:8:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Coding Bootcamp/Week14/ur-rich-fsf-pt-02-2021-u-c/Bootcamp14_TechBlog/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Coding Bootcamp/Week14/ur-rich-fsf-pt-02-2021-u-c/Bootcamp14_TechBlog/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Coding Bootcamp/Week14/ur-rich-fsf-pt-02-2021-u-c/Bootcamp14_TechBlog/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Coding Bootcamp/Week14/ur-rich-fsf-pt-02-2021-u-c/Bootcamp14_TechBlog/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/ep9k/Desktop/Coding Bootcamp/Week14/ur-rich-fsf-pt-02-2021-u-c/Bootcamp14_TechBlog/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Coding Bootcamp/Week14/ur-rich-fsf-pt-02-2021-u-c/Bootcamp14_TechBlog/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Coding Bootcamp/Week14/ur-rich-fsf-pt-02-2021-u-c/Bootcamp14_TechBlog/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

If I move `main.handlebars` up one level into the views directory, I get the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Coding Bootcamp/Week14/ur-rich-fsf-pt-02-2021-u-c/Bootcamp14_TechBlog/views/layouts/main.handlebars'
```

If it is helpful, here is the github repo: https://github.com/epurpur/Bootcamp14_TechBlog

Comment: Judging by the errors, it looks like you need a `main.handlebars` in `views/` which is the view your controller is referencing when it does `res.render('main')` _and_ you need a `main.handlebars` in `views/layouts/` because the view engine is looking for a layout there.

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You should look here to [reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars). You forgot to add file in `views` folder. In `homeRoutes.js` you called it `main` (**I modestly think this is confusing..in example from reference you have** `home`). So if you create this file than this code will work without any issues!